# creating new dataframe by combining different groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```
          id      source                 Date       CVI
67092  10365     sat     2016-11-20 00:00:00      1.9
67093  10365     nel-2   2016-11-20 00:00:00      1.5
67094  10365     sat     2016-12-06 00:00:00   1.436964
67095  10365     sat     2016-12-22 00:00:00        NaN
67096  10365     sat     2017-01-07 00:00:00   4.835949
67097  10365     sat     2017-01-23 00:00:00  10.033607
...      ...         ...                  ...        ...
723    84650  nel-2      2020-04-03 00:00:00   5.085851
724    84650  nel-2      2020-04-08 00:00:00   4.375207
725    84650  nel-2      2020-04-13 00:00:00   0.040688
726    84650  nel-2      2020-04-18 00:00:00   3.151000
```

From the dataframe above, I would like to create a new dataframe where `id` for same `Date` and different `source` are in same row. e.g. the output should look like:

```
         id              Date                 sat_CVI   nel-2_CVI
0       10365        2016-11-20 00:00:00        1.9        1.5
```

I tried using groupby but it does not do what I want. Please note that the resulting table has only those rows where the same `id` has a `CVI` value for the same `Date` for both the `source`

Comment: @jezrael, this is different from using just pivot table since I only want those rows where the same `Date` is present for both the sources for the same `id`

Comment: Sorry, so not understand, is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Because `1.5` from output is not in input DataFrame

Comment: thanks @jezrael, I updated the example to be MCVE

Comment: Super, so `df.pivot_table(index=['id','Date'],columns='source', values='CVI')` not working for you?

Comment: it is close, but it seems to include even rows with `Date` where one `source` has data and the the other one does not. I do not want such rows to be included. E.g. if on `Date` `2020-04-03 00:00:00` only `nel-2` has data in `CVI` column, then that row should not be included in output

Comment: I guess I could drop rows where either of the resulting `source` columns has NaNs. Thanks!

Comment: hmmm, it seems more complicated, because pivot_table create new missing values. So you need filter first if for each Date are sources `sat` and `nel-2`, then remove all another Dates with one row (from sample data stay only first 2 rows) and last step is pivoting. What do you think?

Comment: @jezrael, I meant dropping rows `after` the `pivot_table` solution you specified. That should work I think, or am I missing something?

Comment: There is problem if want distingush missing values already in source data (these values need in output) with missing values created by `pivot_table` - this values need remove from output data.

Comment: thanks @jezrael, we can safely ignore any values that are already missing. Your current solution works for me. I will be happy to accept.

Comment: hmm, so `df.pivot_table(index=['id','Date'],columns='source', values='CVI').dropna()` is what need?

Comment: yes, that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no duplicated triples `id`, `Date` and `source` values use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape and then chnage columns names by [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) with remove rows with missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['id','Date','source'])['CVI']
         .unstack()
         .add_suffix('_CVI')
         .dropna()
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df1)
      id                 Date  nel-2_CVI  sat_CVI
0  10365  2016-11-20 00:00:00        1.5      1.9
```

If possible duplicates first solution fail is necessary [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) (it also working for no duplicated triples, then is no aggregation) with some aggregate fucntion like `sum`, `mean` instead `set_index` with `unstack`:

```
print (df)
          id source                 Date        CVI
67092  10365    sat  2016-11-20 00:00:00   1.900000 <- duplicated triple
67092  10365    sat  2016-11-20 00:00:00   1.000000 <- duplicated triple
67093  10365  nel-2  2016-11-20 00:00:00   1.500000
67094  10365    sat  2016-12-06 00:00:00   1.436964
67095  10365    sat  2016-12-22 00:00:00        NaN
67096  10365    sat  2017-01-07 00:00:00   4.835949
67097  10365    sat  2017-01-23 00:00:00  10.033607
723    84650  nel-2  2020-04-03 00:00:00   5.085851
724    84650  nel-2  2020-04-08 00:00:00   4.375207
725    84650  nel-2  2020-04-13 00:00:00   0.040688
726    84650  nel-2  2020-04-18 00:00:00   3.151000

df1 = (df.pivot_table(index=['id','Date'],columns='source', values='CVI', aggfunc='sum')
         .add_suffix('_CVI')
         .dropna()
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df1)
      id                 Date  nel-2_CVI  sat_CVI
0  10365  2016-11-20 00:00:00        1.5      2.9
```